# SQL logical not equals

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I know this is a logic problem, however I am fairly new to SQL and do not know how to get through this one:

I have two tables.

`Table A` has a distinct `ID`.
`Table B` is used to store bits of data pertaining to any row in `Table A`.

`Table B` may have multiple rows which reference a single row of `Table A`.

How can i search for all of A's `ID's` in `table B` for which a single row of `B` does not equal a certain value?

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_a_id FROM table_b b WHERE b.meta_key != 'hidden'
```

since `table_a_id` is not distinct, this will return `table_a_id's` as long as the only row in `table B` for that particular `table_a_id` is not `'hidden'`.  Obviously it works if i am looking for each `table_a_id` which is hidden (if I use = instead of !=), but how do I accomplish the opposite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT table_a_id
FROM table_b b 
GROUP BY table_a_id
HAVING SUM(b.meta_key = 'hidden') = 0;
```

An alternative is to use `not exists`:

```
select a.id
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where a.id = b.table_a_id and b.meta_key = 'hidden'
                 );
```

This version actually has the advantage that it will show all rows from `table_a`, even when there are no rows in `table_b`.  The first version will only show ids that have some data in `table_b`, just not the `'hidden'` values.

Comment: Thanks!  The latter option worked best; the Query I originally asked about was a part of a larger Query on Table A, so the latter really simplified the entire thing - just had to add a few more AND clauses to the end to get what I needed.